# convergence of rather uncommon series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

While working on my physics bachelor thesis i encountered the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{m=0}^n \frac{x^m}{1-x^{(m+1)}}
$$

For $|x|<1 $ this sum converges. But i don't know how to get the analytic expression of this result.

I already tried in a rather unsophisticated way to calculate the sum for different values of x between 0 and 1 and fit it to a function. I obtained the best results with the function $f(x)=\frac{a \cdot x}{b + c \cdot x}$ but there is still a significant difference. It looks like that:
[deleted since it was the wrong sum]

Does anyone know the result of this sum? Or how to get it?

EDIT: i used the wrong sign in the denominator. it should be $ \frac{x^n}{1-x^{(n+1)}}$ like it is now.

EDIT2: I have now enough reputation to post images, thanks :)

EDIT3: Turned out i underestimated my problem. It has actually the form of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{m=0}^n \frac{x^m}{1-x^{(m+1)}}$$
I don't even know, if this expressible in elementary functions ...
i think i am going to try to approximate it numerically.
But if someone finds a solution i'd still be happy to use that :)

Comment: `\Pi` $\to$ `\prod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$ with positive integer coefficients $(a_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ and radius of convergence $1$.

An easy upper bound is $a_n\leqslant2^n$ for every $n\geqslant0$. When $n\to\infty$, $a_n\to\infty$. The first $11$ coefficients are $a_0=1$, $2$, $2$, $4$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $10$, $12$, $16$, and $a_{10}=20$.

This is sequence [A087135](http://oeis.org/A087135), thus $a_n$ is the number of partitions of $n+1$ where all parts except possibly the two smallest are distinct.

"Unfortunately, there [does not seem to be any known] simple analytic expression for this function".

Answer (score 1):

*This is an answer to the first version of the question.*

Unfortunately, there is no simple analytic expression for this function. On the other hand, it is related to well know functions.For instance
$$
F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x^{n+1}} = \frac{L(x)}{x} - \frac{1}{1-x},
$$
where $L(x)$ is the [Lambert Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html)
$$
L(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}.
$$
You can also express it with the [$x$-Polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html):
$$
F(x) = \frac{\psi_x(1)}{x\ln x} + \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x\ln x} - \frac{1}{1-x}.
$$

Comment: sorry, that i uploaded the wrong version fist. I thought i was far enough to already ask, but i apparently wasn't. I'll think over it longer before i post. Thank you for your effort!