# Does this discrete distribution have a name?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

[I encountered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429953) a discrete probability distribution $P_\lambda$ on $\mathbb N$ with $\lambda \in (0,1]$. It is of the form

$$P_\lambda(n) = c \cdot \prod_{i=0}^{n} \frac{\lambda^{i}}{1-\lambda^{i+1}}$$

for $n \in \mathbb N$, where $c=c(\lambda)$ enables the scaling, so that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P_\lambda(n)=1$.

Is this a common distribution? Has it a name?

EDIT:
leonbloy, Sudeep you were correct. I swapped $i$ and $n$ in the fraction. It is corrected now.

Comment: Something looks wrong in the product, the index `i` is absent in the factor.

Comment: Your expression inside product for $P(n)$ is independent of $i$, (the index of product). Is that the expression you intended? Or should it be $P(n) = c \cdot \prod_{i=0}^{n} \frac{\lambda^{(i-1)}}{1-\lambda^i}$ for $n > 0$?

Comment: "Unfortunately, there [does not seem to be any known] simple [name] for this [distribution]".

Comment: Including $i=0$ in the product produces a denominator $0$, which is usually not a good sign.

Comment: @GEdgar Knowing that this is a followup of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429953/convergence-of-rather-uncommon-series), the correct version is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ \ \ \ \text{No.}\ \ \ \ $$

Comment: Answers should be backed up by references...

Comment: @GEdgar Please go ahead (this is CW). (I am curious to see a reference giving a list of distributions which have *no* name.)

Comment: Such a document does indeed exist and the number of entries in the list happens to equal _[the smallest positive integer not definable in fewer than twelve words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox)._ :-)

Comment: @DilipSarwate It seems I just upvoted a comment... :-)